# I want to archive data.How do it in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to archive data in my system.I used Mysql and Laravel 5.3 to develop this system.Now i created to delete selected row.

EmployeeController.php

```
public function deleteEmployeeEntries($id, Request $request) {
    $test = $this->Employee->delete($id);
    if($test) {    
        $data['message'] = 'Record has been deleted successfully!';
    } else {
        $data['error'] = "Couldn't delete the user";
    }
    return $data;
}
```

EmployeeRepository.php

```
public function delete($id) {
    $data=$this->model->where('id','=',$id)->delete();
    return $data;
}
```

But i need to archive.I maintain the status column in database.how i change the status 1 to 0 ??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update status in some table, you need to use `update()`

```
Model::where('id', 5)->update(['status' => 0]);
```

Or `save()`

```
$model = Model::find(5);
$model->status = 0;
$model->save();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#updates

Comment: thank you for your guidence.

Comment: @RuwanthaSameera if this is all you are looking for, then your question is a duplicate